# question on $\mathbb{Q} \otimes R[G]$ his maximal ideals, the action of a Galois group on it

Tags: commutative-algebra, representation-theory, galois-theory

Reasoning on a question a friend posed me, i've found a question in the following setup:

Suppose you have a finite group G, now you can pass to the algebra $\mathbb{Q} \otimes R[G]$ where the second is the representation ring of G. Now i think i've a proof for the following(some i'm pretty sure, others i've come there just with conjecturally toughts and with start of proofs):

1)Since it is a finite dimensional algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ is an artin ring, and is clearly with no nilpotent, so it is just a product of finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\prod_{i=1}^{j}\mathbb{Q}[x]/p_i(x)$, with $p_i$ irreducible. Each quotient correspond to some evaluation on some coniugacy classes(a sort of analogy with the fact that maximal ideals of C(X) corresponds to points of it), and so this should imply that each factor is in a cyclotomic extension,so is Galois, with cyclic Galois group.

2)Now i call K the minimal field that contain all the evaluation obtained in 1), K is an abelian extension, and i think i've found a way(supposing 1) true, and some other reasoning that should be true but quite lenghty and i'm just betting they work)to make $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ acting on $\mathbb{Q} \otimes R[G]$, and the action should be isomorphic to the pointwise action of $\prod_{i=1}^{j}Gal(\mathbb{Q}[x]/p_i(x)/\mathbb{Q})$ and in particular gives an isomorphism between these two groups $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \prod_{i=1}^{j}Gal(\mathbb{Q}[x]/p_i(x)/\mathbb{Q})$ wich is coerent with the fact that the second is a product of cyclic groups and the first is abelian.  I think to have found also some other properties of this action, but for the moment i stop here and ask

Is all this true?
Thanks for any comments, correction, advice.

p.s: i didn't try any counterexample yet, so there could be easily and trivial(i write this because it can help for answering)